# C# Reports tablix keeps pushing controls under it

Tags: c#, report, reporting

Hello i have a problem with tablix in reports. I have a report with image (template) and in that image i have tablix and under it some textboxes with other data.
I put tablix into Rectangle (tablix has parent connection to that rectangle), but my textboxes below are still getting pushed down by expanding tablix.
It also expands my rectangle that cointains tablix as you can see in the images below.

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZPdj.png)

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8rrF.png)

Any idea why this keeps happening even when i used rectangles as containers?
Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Remove the rectangle issue will go away

Comment: When i had no rectangles there it was still pushing components under tablix